# PHPExcel row break not working

Tags: phpexcel, page-break

. . . . 
I am using Codeigniter 3.1 and PHPExcel 1.8.

I have a function that creates a PHPExcel Object and returns it and the other function outputs the Excel to browser

Everything is working perfectly fine. Now on specific rows I need to add page breaks.

```
if($count == 4 || ($count > 4 && (($count - 4) % 6 == 0))){
    //echo("A - $row <br>Count - $count<br><hr>");
    $sheet->setBreak('A' . $row , PHPExcel_Worksheet::BREAK_ROW );
}
```

The echo is giving me my required rows, so the condition is working fine. The only issues is . . . . . page break not working. So any suggestions?

Following is the code used for generating the file

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel5");

$objWriter->save("php://output");
```

Comment: Pagebreak is only appropriate for the Excel2007 or Excel5 Writers; which Writer are you using?

Comment: I am using Excel5

Comment: And you've printed it through MS Excel, and it ignores the line breaks?

Comment: yes adding the setbreak line has made no difference at all :(

Comment: How does it show when you do print preview from MS Excel? What version of MS Excel are you using? I've not been able to replicate this problem with either Excel2007 or Excel5 Readers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. Initially I was using the setbreak function while inserting rows. and whenever the condition meets, call the function. I was going through the code, got an idea, implemented it and solved. Instead of calling the function setbreak during row generation, i stored the row reference in an array, and then after doing all page settings, at the end looped the array and called setbreak on the rows and it worked :). Thanks Mark as discussing with you has helped me twice now :)

Comment: Not sure quite how I helped, but glad that you found a way to make it work for you